# How should one include the license notice of a frontend framework?

Tags: web-development, licenses

Angular and VueJS are both under the MIT license, which contains the following declaration:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Where would one ideally include their license, to correctly abide by its requirements? Does this refer to the source code **only**, meaning i would only declare it it me `LICENSE.md` file in the source of my project, or does this have to be accessible to the visitors of the web app which will be the result of using those frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

Every Wordpress sites have an url like this one : [/license.txt](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/license.txt) (but most of the time access is forbidden or redirect to the home/404)

[Here's an example](http://usainbolt.com/license.txt)
[Here's another](https://techcrunch.com/license.txt)

So feel free to add a **license.txt** but that's not an obligation.